# Eclipse Formatter: Remove Empty Line Between Annotation and its target

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I'm configuring the autoformatter for my project and I'm not able to make sure, that between an Annotation and its target is no empty line.

This:

```
@Entity



public class JuelKlasse {
```

Will be formatted to:

```
@Entity

public class JuelKlasse {
```

Because I set *Blank Lines -> Number of empty lines to preserve* to 1, which is what I want for example for the space between two methods.

But what I want is:

```
@Entity
public class JuelKlasse {
```

What I don't want is:

```
@Entity public class JuelKlasse {
```

I have not found any specific setting to keep annotations right in the line before its target. Does something like that exist?

Comment: What is your setting for Line wrapping policy in "Line Wrapping -> Annotaions" ? It should be "Do not wrap after single annotation"

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) and I don't have that option.
I only have Line Wrapping -> Wrapping settings -> Annotations -> Element-value pairs with possible settings:
Do not wrap,
wrap where necessary,
wrap first element others where necessary,
wrap all elements,
every element on a new line,
wrap all elements indet all but the first element,
wrpa all elements except first element if not necessary